# MediaRecorder and VideoSource.SURFACE, stop failed: -1007 (a serious Android bug)

Tags: android, android-canvas, mediarecorder, surface, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to record `MediaRecorder` without using `Camera` instance but using `Surface` video source (yes it's possible, but it turned out that it's not that perfect) - `mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);`

I just write what the issue:

**Next code works only on some devices and works temporary on some devices after a recent device rebooting or doesn't work at all**

If it doesn't work ok `MediaRecorder.stop()` method fails with the next error

> E/MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007 W/System.err:
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed. at
>
> android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)

recorder mp4 file is too small size (kilobytes) and it can't be played

*Tested devices:*

works on Lenovo P2, Xiaomi Mi A1

doesn't work on Xiaomi Redmi 5, Sony Xperia, Xiaomi Redmi 4 Prime

Also you can read comments in my code to understand the issue better

```
new Thread(() -> {

    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "test_media_recorder_surface_source.mp4");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }

    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280, 720);
    mediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(24);

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();

        int sleepTime = 1000 / 24;

        Surface surface = mediaRecorder.getSurface();

        mediaRecorder.start();

        // record something (we can also record frames here from onPreviewFrame byte arrays)
        // e.g. convert raw frame byte[] to Bitmap using mb OpenCV and then draw bitmap on canvas
        // using canvas.drawBitmap(...)
        // here we record just blue background...
        for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++) { // 5 seconds, 24 fps
            Canvas canvas = surface.lockCanvas(null);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
            surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // on many devices stop fails with RuntimeException -1007 error code
        // I guess it works ok 100% only for modern powerful devices...
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        // E/MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007
        // W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
        // at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)

        // recorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();
        // I get file with very small size (kilobytes) and it can't be played

        // ######## RESULTS ######

        // WORKS OK ON:
        // - Lenovo P2 (Android 7)
        // - Xiaomi Mi A1 (Android 8)

        // DOESN'T WORK ON (stop fails with -1007, small video file and can't be played):
        // - Xiaomi Redmi 5 (Android 7)
        // - Sony Xperia (I don't remember the exact model and Android OS)
        // - Xiaomi Redmi 4 Prime (Android 6) *

        // * p.s. on Xiaomi Redmi 4 Prime it works some time after rebooting the device
        // if I leave this smartphone for a while and try again it will fail again
        // until I reboot the device...

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}).start();
```

**UPDATE #1**
seems some progress what could be the issue - codes issue (mp4/h264)

it works better with WEBM/VP8, videos can be played now, but something wrong with fps, it shows 1000 in proporties

```
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.WEBM);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.VP8);
```

also MediaRecord doesn't record audio when using

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.VORBIS);
```

check [Android MediaRecorder crashes on stop when using MP4/H264 and a resolution bigger than 720p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658485/android-mediarecorder-crashes-on-stop-when-using-mp4-h264-and-a-resolution-bigge)
so it also happens when you use `MediaRecorder` and `MediaProjection` to record/capture device Screen (because it also uses `Surface`...)

**UPDATE 2**
yes seems vp8 codec works fine, but one problem for webm container - NO AUDIO!

buggy Android just doesn't support VORBIS/OGG audio encoding... https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#audio-formats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess there is no solution

so the answer: MediaRecorder/Android is buggy or Mobile companies didn't care of all Android features while developing their devices

**Update**

`MediaCodec` is also buggy with canvas

```
mSurface = mMediaCodec.createInputSurface();
mSurface.lockHardwareCanvas()
```

It works on most devices with `MediaCodec` but still some devices may fail to record video correctly using this method

So **final answer**: don't ever use `lockCanvas` or `lockHardwareCanvas` when working with `MediaCodec` or `MediaRecorder`, it's buggy.. **At least on old phones, newer Android versions I guess should work fine**

The only way - OpenGl ES

other links about issue:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/issues/86
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111433520

Comment: is there a way to record a canvas drawing/animation using Media Recorder? do you have a working solution please